# meteor install failed on my mac and linux

Tags: meteor

My friends and me tried so many times and failed. We can access the site `https://www.meteor.com`

but when we use command

```
sudo curl http://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

we get fail command:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6674    0  6674    0     0   2473      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--  2473
Downloading Meteor distribution

curl: (35) Server aborted the SSL handshake
Installation failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of some people having issues with certain versions of curl that come along with VPN and other packages. Have you confirmed that you're using the instance of curl in /usr/bin ?

```
sudo /usr/bin/curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

If that still fails, what is the output of 'curl -v https://install.meteor.com/' ?